# Why is $1 \over x$ a function?

Tags: functions, relations

I have just learned that every relation which is both *left-total* and *right-unique* is called *map* or *function*.

Why is $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, x \mapsto {1 \over x}$ or as relation $G = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \mid y = {1 \over x}\}$ a function?

To be *left-total*, $\forall x \in \mathbb{R} \exists y \in \mathbb{R}: (x,y) \in G$ must be true. But that is not true for $x=0$, since ${1 \over 0} \notin \mathbb{R}$.

Is that special case simply ignored since it is not "allowed" to divide by zero or am I missing something?

Comment: Usually, one would specify $x\ne0$ in the beginning... but it appears someone forgot this.  XD

Comment: Typically a function is defined only where it is definable, so assume that. This is noteworthy especially for functions like $\ln(x)$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $x \mapsto \frac{1}{x}$, for the reason you state: it doesn't assign a value to the input $0$.

The function $x \mapsto \frac{1}{x}$ is usually given with domain $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$.

Comment: I have never seen it so far in my assignments. Maybe it will appear from now on. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes functions are lazily defined with implicit domains which you take to be the largest set of $\mathbb R$ that the function makes sense. This occurs frequently in first-year calculus courses, but should be more explicit if you are operating at your level of detail.

Your relation as defined is not a function over $\mathbb R$, but rather $\mathbb R \setminus \{0\}$. However, you can make it a function from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$ by explicitly defining a value for $f(0)$ to make it left-total.